# angular datepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, datepicker

[angular4-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker)

it's give error like :

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mydatepicker'

also give compile time error at here :

> import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';

report.module.ts :

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';
@NgModule({
  imports: [  
    MyDatePickerModule,
    FormsModule
  ] 
})
```

report.component.ts :

```
import {IMyDpOptions} from 'mydatepicker';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit { 

  public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
};
}
```

report.component.html :

```
 <my-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" [(ngModel)]="filterData.firstDate" required></my-date-picker>
```

I use :

> Angular: 5.2.1
>   Angular CLI: 1.6.5

Comment: post your code module.ts and component code

Comment: Are you using material design or normal form?

Comment: I use normal form.

Comment: show your template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use `npm install mydatepicker --save` instead of `npm install angular4-datepicker --save`

it's works for me.

thanks